# Odoo 12 : Change the name of the menuitem of an inherited view

Tags: inheritance, menuitem, odoo-12

I want to change the name of a menuitem( All timesheets to All activities) by view inheritance but it doesn't work.

This is original menu

```
<menuitem id="timesheet_menu_activity_all"
           name="All Timesheets"
           parent="menu_hr_time_tracking"
           action="timesheet_action_all"/>
```

another one is a new menu

```
 <menuitem id="hr_timesheet.timesheet_menu_activity_all"
            name="All Activities"
            parent="hr_timesheet.menu_hr_time_tracking"
            action="hr_timesheet.timesheet_action_all"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code to change the name of existing `menu Item` name.

```
<record model="ir.ui.menu" id="hr_timesheet.timesheet_menu_activity_all">
    <field name='name'>All Activities</field>
</record>
```

The menu entries are stored as records of the `'ir.ui.menu'` object type, so it is possible to use 'record' XML tags to update `'ir.ui.menu'` records by providing '**model**' and '**id**' attributes to identify the existing record.

Thanks